# React TypeScript generics: How to resolve " not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LibraryManagedAttributes"?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, higher-order-components

I'm creating a higher order component (HOC) that will provide some property values to a component, so that this component can be used by a parent component, without supplying those values.

## What I want to achieve

I want to be able to wrap this component:

```html
<MyInnerComponent someProp="some value" suppliedProp="supplied value" />
```

in the HOC:

```js
const WrappedComponent = wrap(MyInnerComponent, () => ({suppliedProp: "supplied value"}))
```

and then use it from a parent component like this:

```html
<WrappedComponent someProp="some value" />
```

so that it renders like this:

```html
<div>someProp: some value, suppliedProp: supplied value</div>
```

I have implemented the HOC:

```js
export function wrap<
  DataProps,
  InnerComponentType extends React.ComponentType<Props>,
  Props extends DataProps
>(
  InnerComponent: InnerComponentType,
  dataPropsProvider: (
    props: Omit<React.ComponentProps<InnerComponentType>, keyof DataProps>
  ) => DataProps
) {
  return (
    outerProps: Omit<React.ComponentProps<InnerComponentType>, keyof DataProps>
  ) => {
    const dataProps: DataProps = dataPropsProvider(outerProps);
    // This is the problem:
    return <InnerComponent {...outerProps} {...dataProps} />;
  };
}
```

## The problem

Upon rendering the `InnerComponent`, there's a TypeScript error:

> Type 'Omit<ComponentProps, keyof DataProps> & DataProps' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LibraryManagedAttributes<InnerComponentType, Props>'

## What I've tried

Adding the constraint `IntrinsicAttributes & LibraryManagedAttributes<InnerComponentType, Props>` to the `DataProps` parameter:

```js
export function wrap<
  DataProps extends JSX.IntrinsicAttributes & JSX.LibraryManagedAttributes<InnerComponent, Props>,
  InnerComponentType extends React.ComponentType<Props>,
  Props extends DataProps
>(
```

... but this is a circular constraint.

I'm not sure I understand the requirement for extending `JSX.IntrinsicAttributes` and `JSX.LibraryManagedAttributes`.

How can I satisfy the requirement?

[There's a Code Sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-dewdney-0cyf8h?file=/src/App.tsx).